# JFileChooser not showing, is there something wrong with my ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I'm currently working on an selfmade Editor. The "Open" and "Save as" JMenu's are already set and appear when I start the program. The problem is they don't react on my clicking. I think there's a problem in the ActionListeners I'm missing.

```
savebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileread = new JFileChooser();
                if(fileread.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    File file = fileread.getSelectedFile();

                    try {
                        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                        String text = "";
                        for( int i = 0; i<=br.read();i++) {
                            text.concat(br.readLine());
                        }
                        textbereich.setText(text);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
});
```

Maybe you can find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The "Open" and "Save as" JMenu's are already set

A JMenu doesn't respond to an ActionListener.

You should create a "File" menu, then you add "Open" and "Save As" as `JMenuItems` of the "File" menu. Then the ActionListeners will work.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Also, when you read a file into a text component, just use the `read(...)` method of the text components to read the text into the component. Don't read the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to set the action for JMenu instead of **JMenuItem**.

You have to change the code from

```
JMenu savebtn = new JMenu("Save");
```

to

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem savebtn = new JMenuItem("Save");
fileMenu.add(savebtn);
```

Go through this tutorial for using menus
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: (1-) this answer was given 8 hours earlier. There is no need to clutter the forum with the same answer.